# How to efficiently determine if the user has actually produced input in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, textchanged

Working on a text editor here...

I'm trying to figure out if the user has actually caused any changes in a textbox after a keyboard event has occurred. Obviously if they press a standard keys like, <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>, it will fire, but I'm more interested if there's a way, besides enumerating all possible, non-input options.

I will note that I realize the state of the textbox could be compared before and after, but that seems like it would be a poor use of memory, and CPU time if it was a large document. Also, I'm using the `Modified` property for another purpose, and since it only fires when it changes, that also isn't an options, as it will more often than not be in the `true` state.

I've though about the enumeration side, but that also seems inefficient, as, I would not only have to ensure that every non-input option is there, but also check for all the exceptions. One example that comes to mind:

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed, I don't want to do anything, unless I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

However, if there's nothing in the clipboard, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> shouldn't do anything, and if nothing is selected, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> shouldn't do anything.

I'm sure there are more exceptions that I'm not thinking of right now.

As for the Modified property, when that changes I'm using it to modify the widow title with/without an asterisk based on it's state. So if I reset the property, it will remove the asterisk.

Comment: What about hashing the content?

Comment: @SteveB Feel free to add that method. Though I think since .NET already fires the `TextChanged` event, that is the fastest method, as all it does it add a function call and whatever code is inside the function.

Answer (score -1):

In the famous method of [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), I ended up solving this simply by asking it. If I've missed a more efficient option, please let me know.

The first and what would seem the be the simpliest option would be to use the `TextChanged` event, which I actually learned about by adding tags to my post.

If for whatever reason that doesn't work for the future reader, then using the `ModifiedChanged` event would be the next best option.

Simply put, in my situation, the asterisk only goes away when the document is saved. By setting a flag, I can use an `if` statement to determine if I need to remove it, and then reset the flag at that point. Something like this:

```
void saved(){
    // ...
    saved = true;
}

// ...
if(saved){
    removeAsterisk();
    saved = false;
}
// ...
```

Those seem to be the best options, which are neither long in code, nor consuming in time by checking 100k characters.